# cakePHP 2.3.8 and phpExcel 1.7.9 can't open output

Tags: php, cakephp, phpexcel, cakephp-2.3

I have a reference and follow my code here, except that I'm using the latest version now.

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/melgior/2010/01/26/simple-excel-spreadsheet-helper

I have configured everything, and got to the point that I managed to download the excel generated it. My problem now is I can't open the file it says `Can't Open the File because the file format or extension is not valid.`

I opened the output using notepad and there lot of errors there that I can't understand and some not readable characters.

Here is my code for Controller:

```
public function participants($id = null) {
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            $this->set('event', $this->Computer->findById($id));
        }
```

Here is my code for View:

```
<?php
$this->Excel->generate($event['Computer'],'Participants list '
    .$event['Computer']['control']);
?>
```

Here is my code for ExcelHelper _output:

```
function _output($title) {
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$title.'.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($this->xls);
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: maybe you have some kind of error that kake tries to output in your excel file. Try commenting header line in your _output function and see wich errors you get in your browser. Also: you are using excel2007, did you remember to import the right libraries (first two lines of the helper)? Finally: are you sure you put PHPExcel files in the right path? You should see a file named PHPExcel.php in `App/Vendor/excel/`

Comment: `I opened the output using notepad and there lot of errors` like what (add them to the question)?

Comment: I have solved this putting ob_end_clean above the header..It seems without it all codes in the layout are included in the excel.